# Create UI like PassCode functionality (as reference look at dropbox application)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am new to the iOS SDK. I have a requirement to create a UI similar to the passcode entry in the Dropbox application. I have few questions as below:

1. How to create secure text field which does not show cursor blinking
   on that?
2. How to create numberic keyboard which is always available on
   particular UIViewController?
3. How to receive event of keyboard key press so I can set pressed
   value in particular text field?

I have read a number of posts and articles on this, but none of those are helpful to me. Some posts has technique like create one dummy text field invisible and keyboard is attached to this textfield. For every entry in this text field update four passcode entry text fields accordingly.

I hope answers to above question will help me to create same passcode entry UI.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at existing implementations like [KKPasscodeLock](https://github.com/aporat/KKPasscodeLock), [EAPasscodeLock](https://github.com/eaceto/EAPasscodeLock) or [pinview](https://github.com/guicocoa/pinview). You can download these for free and take a look at the source code (or just use the code in your own app).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do it like the Calculator app? You make a View with a TextField(non-editable/secure) and lots of Buttons and don't use any keyboard. If you hit the buttons you add the according character to the TextField, if you hit some kind of remove-button you remove last character in TextField.

If you want a more nicely fashioned text, you could hide the textfield and display dots in a textView(non-editable) according to the length of the string in the hidden textfield.